# Format string with bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

There is something i do not understand: This code works on python3.5, but it gives me an error on python3.4:

```
s='abcd'
s2=b'%s' % s.encode('ascii')
```

Here is the Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

Any idea why it works on `python3.5` and not on `python3.4` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for % formatting was added to bytes and bytearray in Python 3.5 with [PEP 461](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/):

> This PEP proposes adding % formatting operations similar to Python 2's `str` type to `bytes` and `bytearray`.